# How to use 'ruby -e' to execute multiline program?

Tags: ruby

I want to execute program by 'ruby -e' but it executes program if it's in single line but it's not executing if it's multiple line and throws the error. For an example,

```
>ruby -e "puts 'rajagopalan'"
=>rajagopalan
```

but

```
>ruby -e "a=[1,2,3,4,5]
a.each do |i|
   puts i
end
"
```

it throws the error that "a.each do |i|
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
"

Can someone guide me how to execute the mulitiline via `ruby -e`

I have attached image here
[image]

Comment: It executed for me correctly for Ruby 1.9+. Which version are you using and what is the exact error message?

Comment: I am executing on 2.6

Comment: How did you paste the program on command prompt? Copy paste?

Comment: Works fine with 2.6.1. Raj, could you be halucinating?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have attached the image now. Can you please see now?

Comment: You are running it in Windows cmd shell. Newline is likely being treated as end of stream which ruby is considering as the end of instruction within first line. Try https://superuser.com/a/1222011

Comment: @kiddorails Now I have tried your solution and it's not working too, I have pasted the image there. Can you see it?

Comment: Dont miss the quotes. Before a= and after 'end'

Comment: @kiddorails Can you please see the third pic, that is still creating the problem, it says i is not recognized now.

Comment: @kiddorails I have removed all the pic and attached the latest one, can you please have a look at that one?

Comment: Try removing the last caret sign after "end"

Comment: @kiddorails did you try? Its working for you?

Answer (score 1):

you can try `here document` in your shell command:

```
ruby <<END
 a=[1,2,3,4,5]
 a.each do |i|
   puts i
 end
END
```

Hope this helps....

Comment: you missed out your `-e`, Is that deliberate?

Comment: Hi I have attached the image now, can you tell me where I go wrong? Should I need to paste it differently?

Comment: @Rajagopalan:  `-e`  is not needed..  pls go with my solution, it will work..  :)

Comment: Hi, my problem is I can't paste this program into the window cmd. Can you please look at the image which I updated in my question?

Comment: @Rajagopalan: if your are using Windows then i have no idea..  try using IRB for your code..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>ruby -e "a=[1,2,3,4,5]; a.each do |i| puts i; end"
```

Basic idea, use a semi-colon wherever a new-line would be needed.

Comment: I can't paste larger program this way.

Comment: I just type it.

Comment: And the Windows command line has a right button menu with paste.

Comment: Are you serious??? It means the right mouse button menu. If you don't know what a mouse or a mouse button is, I cannot help you.

Comment: I know but I tried and it's not working so I was asking whether you meant something else or what. Here is the program I pasted `C:\Users\rajagopalan.m>ruby -e "a=[1,2,3,4,6]"   ^
More?
More? "a.each do |i|"  ^
More?   "p i"  ^
More? "end"  ^`

Comment: Well, that crap ain't gonna work. All I know is I typed in the line in my response (except for the > prompt) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Ruby. You need to read the manual of your terminal emulator and your shell and figure out how to escape newlines.

As can be seen in the error you posted, you get a shell prompt after the first line, so the shell clearly seems to think the command is finished. Ergo, the shell tries to interpret the Ruby commands as shell commands, which leads to the error.

Comment: I am doing it on windows, so the question is how to do it?

Comment: I understand so how do I inform my command prompt that it's not yet finished?

Comment: Hi I found that this character `^`, but please see my second pic, that too is throwing some other error.

Comment: Strings in `CMD.EXE` need to be surrounded by quotation marks.